# 4 hours in currentTimeMillis()

Tags: java, android

I have simple question, I have the following function and there is argument on it that called `cacheTime`, How can I set it to 4 hours, should I set it to `4 * 3600000`?

```
public static File getCache(String name, Context c, int cacheTime) 
{
    if (cacheTime <= 0)
        return null;
    File cache = new File(c.getCacheDir(), name);
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (cache.exists() && (now - cache.lastModified() < cacheTime))
        return cache;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: 4 * 3600000. It's milliseconds, not seconds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

miliseconds are 1/1000 of a second. So 4 hours would be 4 * 60 * 60 * 1000 = 14,400,000

For cache invalidation this is probably fine. That said, date math is often dangerous.  When dealing with larger units of time than milliseconds one can easily get tripped up during daylight savings transitions, leap seconds and all the other stuff that Calendar is meant to take care of. In some cases that rare imprecision is acceptable, and in others it's not. Be careful when doing date math.

For determining human consumable times in larger units of time such as +1 days, use Calendar.roll().

Comment: I would argue that the *opposite* is true. Four hours is four hours. If some timezone decides to muck with the *local representation of GMT* ... four hours is still four hours if you're using milliseconds. When you're relying on local time is when you usually run into issues.

Comment: This is perfectly fine and may not necessarily be a problem. It won't fail during daylight savings transitions, leap seconds or anything else other than a system clock change if you truly do just want "x hours from now". An hour is an hour, a millisecond is a millisecond regardless. While the issues you mention are common date-related problems, when you're dealing with strictly a difference in duration (as opposed to something like "tomorrow at the same time") it will work just fine.

Comment: @kabuko That's a good point, and I suppose for cache invalidation the result is never meant to be displayed to the user so probably not going to see the result anyway. In the display case if one is careful to run the results of the math through a DateFormat with appropriate timezone you probably safe. I just get itchy when I see people doing date/time related math... such amazingly fertile grounds for bugs :)

Comment: Improved based on kabuko's feedback

Answer (score 6):

Learn to use the handy [TimeUnit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) enum so you can do things like so:

```
TimeUnit.Hours.toMillis(4)
```

And not rely on napkin math and magic numbers all over your code.

Comment: Unfortunately the javadoc for TimeUnit is not clear on what the actual result would be, and 4 is also a magic number. This is a bit more readable however.

Comment: Actually the 4 could be configurable and be read in from a an external properties or passed in as a parameter. You're right about the javadoc not being so clear, but read it like so: Convert 4 hours to miliseconds.

Answer (score 4):

```
// 4 hours * 60 (min/hour) * 60 (sec/min) * 1000 (msec/sec)
getCache(name, c, 4 * 3600 * 1000);
```

Comment: I would reccomend collecting those comments into just one comment above the code. It would be much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

```
4 * 1000 * 3600
```

There are 1000 milliseconds in a second and 3600 seconds in an hour.